# Grouping words according to their lengths c#

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Is it possible to group a string of words according to their lengths into array? I'm trying the following code, but it doesn't work. Thank you.

```
string [] groups =
      from word in words.split(' ')
      orderby word ascending
      group word by word.Length into lengthGroups
      orderby lengthGroups.Key descending
      select new { Length = lengthGroups.Key, Words = lengthGroups };
```

Comment: One of the first google results of "linq group words by length": http://www.programminginterviews.info/2011/06/linq-group-sort-and-count-words-in.html

Comment: yes, but is doesn't work for me. that why I asked.

Comment: It looks like you have changed your question to show you are using `var` instead of `string[]`.  This kind of invalidates my answer now.  Did it solve your problem?  If so, I would change the question back to `string[]` and accept the answer so that this page will make sense to others viewing it.

Comment: Yes Kevin, I mentioned that i have changed the question. Yes I agree with you . thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//string[] words = new string[] { "as", "asdf", "asdf", "asdfsafasd" };
//string[] words = "as asdf asdf asdfsafasd".Split(' ');

var groups = "as asdf asdf asdfsafasd".Split(' ').GroupBy(x => x.Length);

foreach (var lengthgroup in groups)
{
    foreach (var word in lengthgroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word.Length + " : " + word);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Xander, I'm using single string which contains number of words, not array of string.

Comment: I have updated my question, I used words.split. is it correct ?

Comment: @Qaesar why did you update your question? what don't understand about the answers posted?

Comment: Because I don't want to create array first, I want to split the single string into groups based on their lengths directely.

Comment: @Qaesar you're allocating a `string[]` under the hood anyways. It must be an array before you can group! why do you want to do that? it doesn't make your code more readable/maintainable ...

Answer (score 3):

Since the query returns a list of an anonymous type, you should use the `var` keyword:

```
var sentence = "Here are a few words in a sentence";
var words = sentence.Split(' ');

var groups =
  from word in words
  orderby word ascending
  group word by word.Length into lengthGroups
  orderby lengthGroups.Key descending
  select new { Length = lengthGroups.Key, Words = lengthGroups };

// Test the results
foreach (var lengthGroup in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(lengthGroup.Length);

    foreach(var word in lengthGroup.Words)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
    }
}
```

You could also use a dynamic `IEnumerable`:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> groups =
  from word in words
  orderby word ascending
  group word by word.Length into lengthGroups
  orderby lengthGroups.Key descending
  select new { Length = lengthGroups.Key, Words = lengthGroups };
```

Since your result is not a list of strings, it is a list of anonymous types, you can't cast it to an array of strings.  You can cast it to an array of dynamic types, if you wanted to:

```
dynamic[] myArray = groups.ToArray();
```

Comment: Then, how to write the groups back into array ?

Comment: @ Kevin, I think you forgot to split the string, I'm I write ?

Comment: @Qaesar - How are you planning to distinquish between groups when you put them all in a single array? You could have simply sorted them on length if that is what you are after.

Comment: The above code will return a list of objects each with a length and a list of words that match the length.  These objects are not strings.  Perhaps if you gave us an example of your expected output, it would help?  :)

Comment: @Kevin, I tried your code, but there is a problem with word.length.

Comment: Is words a list of strings?  Did you use `word.Length` (upper-case L)

Comment: Nope, it is just one string. I'm no using lower-case.

Comment: @Qaesar if it is a single string with words separated by spaces then the following will create a `string[]` of words `sentence.Split(' ');`

Comment: @Qaesar i'd award the answer to kevin - i just provided the alternative lambda syntax

Comment: @Xander No worries!  I like your solution.  Much more succinct!  It doesn't bother me if you get the tick.  :)

Comment: Sorry Guys, it was my mistake.